# Tab Context Menu for WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking

Tags: contextmenu, menustrip

I'm using the "WeifenLuo.WinFormsUI.Docking" control.

I need to show a context menu by clicking on a document tab.

At the moment I just can show a context menu at the document itself or for the menustrip - but I didn't found a way to bind a menu to the tab.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There exists a property called TapPageContextMenu.

To bind a context menu to tab register on top use:

```
DockContent.TabPageContextMenu
```

Is this what you were looking for?